# How to fix gstreamer v4l2src error when streaming video over usb?

Tags: gstreamer, nvidia-jetson

I am using this command: gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src ! xvimagesink

to stream video over usb on my nvidia jetson nano and I am getting this output:

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED...

ERROR: Pipeline doesn't want to pause.

ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstXvImageSink:xvimagesink0: Could not initialise Xv output

Additional debug info:
xvimagesink.c(1773): gst_xv_image_sink_open (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstXvImageSink:xvimagesink0:

Could not display (null)

Setting pipeline to NULL..

Freeing pipeline...
```

Comment: where is the command?

Comment: gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src ! xvimagesink

Comment: weird - your command works on my jetson with sony and logitch usb cams. what camera do you have?

Comment: it is a flir lepton 3.5